# how to replace characters in a string with integers?

Tags: java

Say I have the the string: " aab + bab = b " and I want to

- replace all the `a` characters with the integer 0,
- replace all the `b` characters with the integer 1

so it will become:

```
001 + 101 = 1
```

what would be the easiest way to do this?

so far I parced the equation into three parts:

```
System.out.println("Enter an Equation of variables");
_inString = _in.nextLine();

    //find the three different parts of the equation
    String _noSpaces = _inString.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    String delims = "[+,=]";
    String[] _tokens = _noSpaces.split(delims);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can chain `replace` methods together

```
String str = " aab + bab = b ";
str = str.replace("a", "0").replace("b", "1");
```

We require an assignment back to 'str' because str.replace() returns a new String and the original string would be unchanged. [Because String is immutable in Java]

Comment: yeah, but I want to replace them with integer values so I can evaluate the equation

Comment: But youre doing string replacement so you have to use Strings (or `chars`). You can still evaluate the resultant `String`

Comment: @Reimeus `String`s can be parsed to get a result for a math expression, using one of several open source APIs.

Comment: @Steven Tell us exactly how you want to evaluate these characters, e.g. individually or as a complete `String`

Comment: I cant use any packages because I need to turn this in for school. I split it into 3 tokens and I want to be able to replace all the characters in the whole string with integers and then see if token[0] + token[1] = token[2]

Comment: I found an answer to help future souls: Integer.parseInt(String s) works

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this:

```
String s = aab + bab = b;

int i = 0;
int i2 = 1;

String ii = i + "";
String ii2 = i2 + "";
```

I use this because say `1` and `0` were not identified. You could setup `i` and `i2` to be changeable if your API/Platform supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you only have binary operands?

Just do

```
replaceAll("a", "0");
replaceAll("b", "1");
```

**Edit**:

Since you want to evaluate your equation, I suggest you used the solution above, then use a java math parser. Several can be found after a quick googling.

My favourite is [Javaluator](http://javaluator.sourceforge.net/en/home/).

Comment: okay is there a way to then evaluate the string to see if the equation is true?

Comment: @Steven Yes. There is. But this would be a separate question, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace single characters with other single characters you can use
[`replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) to avoid regex used in

- [`replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) or
- [`replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

like

```
_inString = _inString.replace('a', '0').replace('b', '1');
```